# Azure PowerShell Scripts - Restrict Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile to Filezilla

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to come up with a combination of Custom Role and PowerShell script that will constrain an AD members capabilities to the following (for a particular web app):

1) Require an interactive login to an AD account

2) Perform a download of a Publish Profile, but only in Filezilla format

The purpose is to provide a "deployer" role with the ability to upload code changes, but not see connection strings, which are visible in Web Deploy publish settings.

I see the necessary level of control in Powershell for downloading only the FileZilla3 FTP Publishing data, and I got that to work, example:

```
Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name test-app -ResourceGroupName test_Group -Format FileZilla3 -OutputFile S:\test.xml
```

I understand the pattern for creating a Custom Role, and for adding actions to it. These look like the actions I might need:

Microsoft.Web/sites/publishxml/Action

microsoft.web/sites/publishxml/read

However, I don't see another level of detail within those actions for constraining the action to only Filezilla3 format.

Question:  is there a way to create a Custom Role specification that would allow an AD member to download publish settings, but only in FileZilla3 format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official docs, there is no ways to create a Custom Role you want. For the details, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftweb).